# Welcome Message JS discord bot

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a discord bot, and when I do the welcome message it doesn't work, I don't get errors but it doesn't work. I don't know why, someone can help me?

Comment: Please provide what you tried. Otherwise how are we meant to see where you went wrong in your code and see why it's not working if you didn't show your code.
Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable those two options in the developer portal:
[image]

Developer portal: https://discord.com/developers/applications